# Pandas lambda group by with more than one condition

Tags: pandas

s1 and s2 work fine here but I don't know why the same groupby will not work for multiple conditions?

```
g = dfopenclosed.groupby('week')
s1=g.apply(lambda x: x[x['status'] =='OPEN']['account_number'].count())
s2=g.apply(lambda x: x[x['status'] =='CLOSED']['account_number'].count())
s3=g.apply(lambda x: x[x['status'] =='OPEN'] & x[x['status2'] =='NEW']['account_number'].count())
```

Comment: At a glance, did you mean to do `(a & b).count()` instead of `a & b.count()` (which just seems very wrong)

Comment: s3=g.apply(lambda x:  x['status'=='OPEN' and 'status2'=='NEW' ]['account_number'].count())

Comment: still doesnt work?

Answer (score 1):

Would this one do the trick for you ?

```
s3=g.apply(lambda x: x[(x['status'] =='OPEN') & (x['status2'] =='NEW')]['account_number'].count())
```

It is important to surround conditions with parenthesis when using the `&`operator because it has very high precedence and could be resolved before your conditions are actually computed.